# Android Q delete File File Operations

Tags: android, android-10.0

RecoverableSecurityException cause delete file fail.

In Android Q, use MediaStore getContentResolver().query() to get the cursor, then use while-loop to get photoUri, use cursor.moveToNext() to combine photoUri add in Arraylist.
file path code like this:

```
 Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)));
```

then, use :

```
 mContext.getContentResolver().delete(photoUri, null, null);
```

always execute RecoverableSecurityException.I Know has a way pop a dialog to delete like this.

```
 ((Activity)mContext).startIntentSenderForResult(e1.getUserAction().getActionIntent().getIntentSender(), 100, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

has anything way to delete file jump over Exception. or other way to delete file. file path store in External Storage like this: pictures/abc.jpg

Comment: Did you find any solution for this question? I am getting the same exception. But, unfortunately I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: don't move the file to app folder, if app create file store in the  folder not face this problem

Comment: I solved this problem by requesting permission. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should take permission to access storage in Android Q.

I solved by using this permission request:

```
if (DEVICE_VERSION >= 29) {
        //NOTE: This method and its functions compatible with API Level 24 and above but I am using for only 29 and above
        List<UriPermission> permissions = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
        if (permissions.isEmpty()) {
            StorageManager manager = getSystemService(StorageManager.class);
            StorageVolume primaryStorageVolume = manager.getPrimaryStorageVolume();
            //For open the permission allowing page
            startActivityForResult(primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent(), STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        } else {
            for (UriPermission up : permissions) {
                String permissionUri = up.getUri().toString();
                if (permissionUri.contains("DCIM") || permissionUri.endsWith("%3A") || permissionUri.endsWith("A")) {
                    requestExternalStoragePermission(); //I also used this method for reading and writing of external storage.
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And then, at the onActivityResult( ) method you should check with STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE and set it by using takePersistableUriPermission( ) :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
        final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(), takeFlags);
    }
}
```

It worked for my case.